# Getting 404 error calling another JSP from link

Tags: spring, jsp, http-status-code-404

I have a menu in my web page, and I have added a new link is not working.  I am getting this error message.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Here is the HTML code for the link.

```
<td><a href="<c:url value="/35yearreunion" />"><img src="images/menu/35-year-reunion.jpg" alt="Memories" /></a></td>
```

I do have a Spring controller method, and this is it.  My web page is named reunion2021.jsp.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/35yearreunion")
public String thirtyfiveYearReunion(Model model) {
    return "reunion2021";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the request method to your controller's method , either this way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/35yearreunion",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String thirtyfiveYearReunion(Model model) {
    return "reunion2021";
}
```

or this way :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/35yearreunion")
public String thirtyfiveYearReunion(Model model) {
    return "reunion2021";
}
```